# How to use html templates to dynamically load data in the chrome extend?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, content-script

I use an iframe to load a webpage in the plug-in. But the content of the webpage is to be dynamically generated. How to achieve it?
I see that some extensions set the src path of the iframe as the HTML file inside the extension, and then display the content. But the HTML content displayed by different websites is inconsistent. How does this work?
I am now loading by setting the srcdoc of the iframe. But this is not my ideal implementation.

I want to dynamically load data in HTML, for example using the following library
https://handlebarsjs.com/installation/#npm-or-yarn-recommended
I tried to achieve in content-script file,But I've never been able to make it

Under the requirements of the latest MV3 syntax, I cannot use HTML templates for dynamic data loading in the extension, and the following problem will always be prompted:

```
EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*".
```

I found that many answers to this question were answered a few years ago, which are basically useless

Can anyone give me a correct answer?

Comment: Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) that shows how you create the iframe. Currently it's unclear why extension's CSP is applied to your webpage as it can't happen normally.